# how to know on FB application invitation of which FB user, some-other FB user join/uses the application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am making an FB application, in which i want to track the user and number of their Application invitation was accepted.

Say User A sent's  an invitation to user B and User C. And D also sent's application invitation   to user B and User C.
How do I know on who's invitation B and C are using the application.

I am using FB apprequest method to invite friends.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Invited To Badge'
    }, requestCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Say User A sent's an invitation to user B and User C. And D also sent's application invitation to user B and User C. How do I know on who's invitation B and C are using the application.

When a user accepts an invite, you’ll get the request IDs transmitted to your app (see [requests docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) for details). *IDs*, plural, because it my be more than one – if the user received two requests for the same app by A and D, then you will get the IDs of both requests, because they’ll both count as “accepted”.

It’s up to you, if you want to count that as an accept for both user A and user D, or if you say you’ll count it only for the one that send the first request. (The request object details have a field `created_time`.)